# How to insert and Update simultaneously to PostgreSQL with sqoop command

Tags: postgresql, hadoop, hive, sqoop

I am trying to insert into postgreSQL DB with sqoop command.

```
sqoop export --connect jdbc:postgresql://10.11.12.13:1234/db --table table1 --username user1 --password pass1--export-dir /hivetables/table/   --fields-terminated-by '|' --lines-terminated-by '\n'  -- --schema schema
```

It is working fine if there is not primary key constrain. I want to insert new records and update old records simultaneously.

I have tried

- `--update-key primary_key` This updates only those primary keys present in both DB(hive and postgreSQL. No insertion)
- `--update-mode allowinsert` - This only does the insert
- `--update-key primary_key  --update-mode allowinsert` - This gives error

> ERROR tool.ExportTool:  Error during export: Mixed update/insert is not supported against the
>   target database yet

Can anyone help me to write sqoop command which insert and update the data to postgreSQL ?

Comment: I think it is not possible - https://issues.apache.org/jira/browse/SQOOP-1270

Answer (score 0, accepted):

According to my internet search, it is not possible to perform both insert and update directly to postgreSQL DB. Instead you can create a storedProc/function in postgreSQL and you can send data there..

```
sqoop export --connect <url> --call <upsert proc> --export-dir /results/bar_data
```

[Stored proc/function](http://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/static/plpgsql-control-structures.html#PLPGSQL-UPSERT-EXAMPLE) should perform both Update and Insert.

Link 1 - https://issues.apache.org/jira/browse/SQOOP-1270

Link 2 - [PLPGSQL-UPSERT-EXAMPLE](http://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/static/plpgsql-control-structures.html#PLPGSQL-UPSERT-EXAMPLE)